# How to add nested objects and array with multiple objects in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, model

LANGUAGE USE : PHP with LARAVEL and MONGO.

I am new to php/laravel, i normally coding in node with mongo and mongoose for the model

What i'm trying to do : I would like to implement a model with multiple objects for example :

```
userInfos {
  name : String,
  mail : String, 
  phone :  String,
  Adress : String
}

//array with multiple objects
userContacts [
  {
    name : String,
    phoneNumber : String,
    mail : String
  }
]
```

for the moment, here is my model, it's working when i'm testing with postman or insomnia

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;


use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model; 


 
class Offer extends Model
{
   protected $connection = 'mongodb';
 
   protected $fillable = [
      'username', 'userPhone'
  ];
}
```

What is the best way to write a model with multiple objects, nested objects, array with objects ?
Thank you.

Comment: In Laravel and using the mongodb library you are using you don't define the model shape so writing a simple model is not different to writing a model with nested objects or arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just follow apokryfos comment and it's working :)

So, in laravel we don't need to define a model (like we will do in nodejs)